# Nested accordions collapse on parent

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a pretty simple accordion and want to nest other ones inside them. How ever when you click to open one of the nested ones, the parent accordion collapses on it. Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion-title').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('.accordion-content').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('.accordion-title').removeClass('active');
            $('.accordion-content').slideUp();
            $(this).addClass('active').next('.accordion-content').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
 <section class="ac-container">
  <h2>Register for Summer Youth Camps</h2>
  <!-- <div class="ui button-primary fluid ">Learn more about Lunch Pass and Extended Care</div> -->

  <form name="cform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="/regcamp.php" method="post">
   <dl class="accordion-title"><div><img src="img/breakfast/american.jpg" alt=""><span>Camper 1 Information</span></div></dl>
   <div class="accordion-content"><p>
    include "camper-1.html"
   </p>
   <dl class="accordion-title"><div><img src="img/breakfast/english.jpg" alt=""><span>Camper 2 Information</span></div></dl>
   <div class="accordion-content"><p>
    include "camper-2.html"
   </p></div>
   
   <dl class="accordion-title"><div><img src="img/breakfast/health.jpg" alt=""><span>Camper 3 Information</span></div></dl>
   <div class="accordion-content"><p>
    include "camper-3.html"
   </p></div>
  </div>

  <dl class="accordion-title"><div><img src="img/breakfast/continental.jpg" alt=""><span>Parent or Guardian</span></div></dl>
  <div class="accordion-content"><p>
   include "parent-guardian.html"
  </p></div>
 </form>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion-title').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('.accordion-content').slideUp();
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('.accordion-title').removeClass('active');
            var $ct = $(this).siblings('.accordion-content').slideUp();
            $ct.find('.accordion-title.active').removeClass('active');
            $ct.find('.accordion-content').slideUp();
            $(this).addClass('active').next('.accordion-content').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3t33601h/)